# Total possible no. of license plates

Tags: combinatorics

I following Susanna Epps book for discrete math & I am not able to solve the following :

> In another state, all license plates consist of from four to six
>   symbols chosen from the 26 letters of the alphabet together with the
>   ten digits 0-9.
>
> a. How many license plates are possible if repetition of symbols is
>   allowed?
>
> b. How many license plates do not contain any repeated symbol?
>
> c. How many license plates have at least one repeated symbol?

Only answer for C is given.

a. $36^4+36^5+36^6$

b. $^{36}P_4+^{36}P_5+^{36}P_6$

c. $ans(a)-ans(b) = 789865128$

but answer in book given as 774,372,096. What I am getting wrong ? Any subtle hint will do.

Comment: Your answer is what I get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct; the answer given by the book is incorrect (it happens sometimes).

[Here is the entry in the official errata for the book](http://condor.depaul.edu/sepp/Errata4e.pdf#page=5) (A-79 – 9.3 #7)

Comment: Oh, thank you ! that's quite a relief.